# Remove defined strings from sentences in dataframe

Tags: regex, r, string

I need to remove defined strings from sentences in data frame:

```
sent1 = data.frame(Sentences=c("bad printer for the money wireless setup was surprisingly easy",
                           "love my samsung galaxy tabinch gb whitethis is the first"), user = c(1,2))

Sentences                                                            User
bad printer for the money wireless setup was surprisingly easy        1
love my samsung galaxy tabinch gb whitethis is the first              2
```

Defined strings for excluding, e.g.:

```
stop_words <- c("bad", "money", "love", "is", "the")
```

I was wondering about something like this:

```
library(stringr)
words1 <- (str_split(unlist(sent1$Sentences)," "))
ddd = which(words1[[1]] %in% stop_words)
words1[[1]][-ddd]
```

But I need it for all items in the list. Then I need to have output table in the same structure as input table **`sent1`**, but without defined strings.

Please, I very appreciate any of help or advice.

Comment: did you try your code ? there are some errors in it (in the definition of `stop_words` you forgot the quotes, `str_split` doesn't exist, at least not in `base` R). Anyway, what exactly would be your desired output ? Because if all you want is get rid of the "stop_words" in the sentences, I guess a `gsub` call would do the job

Comment: Sorry I made some correction in task. Desired output would be the same as sent1 data frame, but without stop_words. i have a lot of stop_words, these are only sample... so according to your suggestion there gonna be 500 gsubs... another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine the stop words and create a regex pattern. Therefore, you only need a single `gsub` command.

```
# create regex pattern
pattern <- paste0("\\b(?:", paste(stop_words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b ?")
# [1] "\\b(?:bad|money|love|is|the)\\b ?"

# remove stop words
res <- gsub(pattern, "", sent1$Sentences)
# [1] "printer for wireless setup was surprisingly easy"
# [2] "my samsung galaxy tabinch gb whitethis first"

# store result in a data frame
data.frame(Sentences = res)
#                                          Sentences
# 1 printer for wireless setup was surprisingly easy
# 2     my samsung galaxy tabinch gb whitethis first
```

Comment: I was posting a `gsub` solution but it was not as nice as yours so better discard and (+1) ;-)